# Why is there a 2" step down into my bathroom?

Tags: bathroom

Why is there a 2 inch step down into my 1931 bathroom?  The bathroom floor is 2 inches below the floor just outside the bathroom door.  It is the original floor in the bathroom as well as the floor outside the bathroom.

Comment: What type of foundation?  What area is the house in?

Comment: Wild guess - It is so that if there is a leak or spill in the bathroom it stays in the bathroom. You effectively have a semi-wet room where the room itself is a 2" overflow pan. Is there a floor drain? What is the floor material in the bathroom and the adjoining hallway? Any pics?

Comment: @Freiheit Or...(awaiting input from questioner about floor materials) it was framed for a "mud-bed" tile install and then floored with something else.

Comment: Our house is in Northern/Central NJ.  I don't know type of foundation (of the bathroom floor)  Our house foundation is cement.  There is no floor drain.  The bathroom floor is the original 1931 small tiles. The flooring right outside the bathroom is hardwood floor.

Comment: The toilet overflowed and flooded the bathroom floor and the water dripped down through the tile into the room below, which is our kitchen.  The water came down through the light fixture.

Comment: This may be one of those questions that the answer is simply "who knows? You'd have to ask the person that built it." 70+ year old houses have plenty of idiosyncrasies :) (one theory: the rest of the floors in your second floor were reinforced at some time with additional subfloors...the bath was not as they wanted to leave the original tile exposed.)

Answer (score 1):

Because when you pour water or want to wash bathroom, water will not leak to the dry part of home near the door.

Comment: The toilet overflowed and flooded the bathroom floor and the water dripped down through the tile into the room below, which is our kitchen.  The water came down through the light fixture.

Answer (score 0):

I'll jump in. The 1-inch range is typical, so a bath mat or entry mat wouldn't interfere with the door. They were meant to be water tight rooms, so caulk or re-caulk the bottoms of everything sitting on the floor.

Otherwise, it may be structural settlement from outright strain, most old places weren't built quite right for the literal tons of the bathroom.

One horrible thing that started to become the new trend was Builder's Grade. Due to bathroom floor construction back then, the structure was lowered to accommodate the double thick bathroom floor. But, the new trend was to put in 1/4-inch low-grade finished floor rather than the standard 3/4-inch quality floor for the rest of the house. You probably got switched backed by the builder to 3/4" & the bath therefore "suffered"...consider a shag carpet mat at the door.